# No Intelisense for custom TagHelper on ModelExpression using [HtmlAttributeName("for")]

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

No intelisense (model property suggestions) when the attribute name on ModelExpression of a custom tag helper is anything other than "**asp-for**"

---

This does **not** work:

`[HtmlAttributeName("for")]
 public ModelExpression ForExpression { get; set; }`

`[HtmlAttributeName("abc-for")]
 public ModelExpression ForExpression { get; set; }`

---

This works as expected - the model properties are listed:

`[HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")]
 public ModelExpression ForExpression { get; set; }`

---

ASP.NET Core 2.2

Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure you rebuild your project after any change in html attribute name for tag helper if you want to see updated intelisense on your views.

Second, make sure that additional selectors are not causing the problem. The `HtmlTargetElementAttribute` have additional properties with which you can narrow down when a tag helper should be run. These additional properties are:

- (HTML) [Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.taghelpers.htmltargetelementattribute.attributes?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Razor_TagHelpers_HtmlTargetElementAttribute_Attributes) like `id` or `disabled`
- [TagStructure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.taghelpers.htmltargetelementattribute.tagstructure?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Razor_TagHelpers_HtmlTargetElementAttribute_TagStructure)
- [ParentTag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.taghelpers.htmltargetelementattribute.parenttag?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Razor_TagHelpers_HtmlTargetElementAttribute_ParentTag)

If you set values to those properties, then you won't see an intelisense on targeted HTML tag if you don't satisfy all of the conditions.

Take this for example:

```cs
[HtmlTargetElement("input")]
public class PlaceholderTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")]
    public ModelExpression ForExpression { get; set; }
}
```

As soon as you write `<input>` tag the intelisense for `ModelExpression` will show up. But if you would add the `disabled` attribute requirement, like this:

```cs
[HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = "disabled")]
public class PlaceholderTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")]
    public ModelExpression ForExpression { get; set; }
}
```

...then the intelisense will show up as soon as you satisfy all of the conditions, which in this scenario is being an `<input>` tag and having a `disabled` attribute.

Comment: However, as I mentioned the issue is not using (asp-for) as the attribute name `[HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")],` anything else does not work, I want to be able to custom attribute name and not be forced to use asp-for to get the model property suggestions

Comment: Could you share your tag helper code? I could try to recreate the problem. Just edit the question, please.